# How to get the bundle product option in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, bundled-product, custom-options

I am new one here. I need to know how can we get the bundle product options that we will set through the admin panel. I have a situation where i need to display three product in the product view page in magento and so for that, I need to fully **customize the product view page**. I am trying to figure out how to solve this problem.MY main troubles are as follows..

1)is it possible to **display  3 product** in the product view page?if yes, give your suggestions

2)how can i get the **bundle product**( i have 3 bundle products only in my site) **options** to a page viewttest.phtml which i added into the view page through layout in order to customize the page.

3)i have **2 drop-down options** common for all 3 products. one  to select the state and other for select the business type and according to this all products price will change. trying to implement it by defining custom options.Is that method is better or any other method for it???how can change the price of products using my custom drop-down menus..

Please help me friends i need a solution for this....and thanks..

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: it was long time ago. I was a baby at that time :) I have solved it 90%, but not fully

Comment: `Zend_Debug::dump($yourThing->getData())` and `get_class_methods()` are your friends.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy answer plz?